# How to access form elements in controller symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've generated the form through entity generator,
I've extended the Cobrand Controller

```
class CobrandController extends Controller
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        // the key used to lookup the template
        $templateKey = 'edit';

        if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('CREATE')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $object = $this->admin->getNewInstance();

        $this->admin->setSubject($object);

        /** @var $form \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
        $form = $this->admin->getForm();
        $form->setData($object);

        if ($this->getRestMethod()== 'POST') {

           // $cobrand = new Cobrand();
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $cobrand=new Cobrand($em);
              $form->bind($this->get('request'));

            $isFormValid = $form->isValid();

            // persist if the form was valid and if in preview mode the preview was approved
            if ($isFormValid && (!$this->isInPreviewMode() || $this->isPreviewApproved())) {
                $this->admin->create($object);

                if ($this->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    return $this->renderJson(array(
                        'result' => 'ok',
                        'objectId' => $this->admin->getNormalizedIdentifier($object)
                    ));
                }

                $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_success','flash_create_success');
                // redirect to edit mode
                return $this->redirectTo($object);
            }

            // show an error message if the form failed validation
            if (!$isFormValid) {
                if (!$this->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_error', 'flash_create_error');
                }
            } elseif ($this->isPreviewRequested()) {
                // pick the preview template if the form was valid and preview was requested
                $templateKey = 'preview';
                $this->admin->getShow();
            }
        }

        $view = $form->createView();

        // set the theme for the current Admin Form
        $this->get('twig')->getExtension('form')->renderer->setTheme($view, $this->admin->getFormTheme());

        return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate($templateKey), array(
            'action' => 'create',
            'form'   => $view,
            'object' => $object,
        ));
    }
}
```

Here's my entity code,

```
class Cobrand
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $logo;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $cobrandedProductsOnly;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $productPrices;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $promocodes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productPrices = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->promocodes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Cobrand
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return Cobrand
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Cobrand
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param string $code
     * @return Cobrand
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
}
```

User will enter the values on the form and I wan't to access those values in the createAction method of controller.

I want to change the value of $name in the controller.
How to access this ?

Thanks,
Faisal Nasir[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after binding request

```
$form->get('name')->setData('new value');
```